# Area routing in .net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, area

I tried to add language route too all pages in an area, but no page found in that specific route. I want to read the {lang} in all pages in the `Admin` area.
I don't want to route all the pages in the area one by one, I have many pages in the Admin area and want to to do that all together.

`options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("AdminPage", "/Admin", "/{lang}/admin");`

What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean the lang route is specific for the Admin area? for other area there no need?